# How to grep and replace this pattern from command line?

Tags: sed, grep

I have plenty of Python2 files with pattern like this

```
datetime(2019, 04, 11)
datetime(2019, 10, 01)
datetime(2019, 04, 05, 1, 1)
```

To migrate this code into Python3 I have to remove leading 0 in 2nd and 3rd datetime argument.

I know how to use sed for simple patterns like this:

```
sed  -e 's/01/1/g' -e 's/02/2/g' -e 's/03/3/g'  my.py
```

But my pattern is more sophisticated: I should modify only 2nd and 3rd argument of datetime(). How to do it with sed or any other  command-line tool?

The following command tries to find  all strings to be modified   in codebase with simple static pattern like this:

```
  find . -name "*.py" | xargs grep datetime |  grep '01\|02\|03\|04\|05\|06\|07'
```

But it also has the same problem as above: the grep pattern is not specific enough - the pattern above should not look at entire string, only on  2nd and 3rd argument of datetime().

Comment: `sed 's/ 0/ /g'`?

Comment: If `sed 's/ 0/ /g'` isn't all you need then [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input out, especially cases where `datetime()` as leading `0`s in the 4th or 5th arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
find . -name "*.py" | xargs -d'\n' sed -i '/datetime/s/0\([0-9]\)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

For your particular example, Python's [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#module-lib2to3) tool is helpful.

You can focus only on the `numliteral` conversions and then convert those.

Given:

```
$ cat f.py
datetime(2019, 04, 11)
datetime(2019, 10, 01)
datetime(2019, 04, 05, 1, 1)
```

You can do:

```
$ 2to3 -n -w --add-suffix=3 -f numliterals f.py
RefactoringTool: Refactored f.py
--- f.py    (original)
+++ f.py    (refactored)
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-datetime(2019, 04, 11)
-datetime(2019, 10, 01)
-datetime(2019, 04, 05, 1, 1)
+datetime(2019, 0o4, 11)
+datetime(2019, 10, 0o1)
+datetime(2019, 0o4, 0o5, 1, 1)
RefactoringTool: Writing converted f.py to f.py3.
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
RefactoringTool: f.py
```

Having replaced `04` with `0o4` now you have a much more tangible target for a regex:

```
$ sed -E 's/([[:space:]]*)0o([[:digit:]]+)/\1\2/g' f.py3
datetime(2019, 4, 11)
datetime(2019, 10, 1)
datetime(2019, 4, 5, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `\( ... \)` expression for matching and saving the `datetime(...,`  part:

```
$ cat example.py | sed  -e 's/\(datetime([^,]*,[ ]*\)0/\1/g' | sed  -e 's/\(datetime([^,]*,[^,]*,[ ]*\)0/\1/g'
datetime(2019, 4, 11)
datetime(2019, 10, 1)
datetime(2019, 4, 5, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Consider avoiding the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and combining the two `sed` scripts into one.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(datetime\([0-9]+, )0?([0-9]+, )0?([0-9]+)/\1\2\3/' file
```

Pattern match on the string `datetime` and only capture the non-zero leading numbers in the 2nd and 3rd parameters.